# Signing for "AUv3FilterExtension macOS" requires a development team

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I want to learn to create Audio Units and have downloaded the AUv3FilterExtension example. I wish to develop and run the component on my Macbook Pro (Catalina). However I get the following error when I try to build using Xcode 11.5:

**Showing All Issues
Build target AUv3FilterExtension macOS of project AUv3Filter with configuration Debug
error: Signing for "AUv3FilterExtension macOS" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'AUv3FilterExtension macOS' from project 'AUv3Filter')**

In *Signing & Capabilities* I have:

- Automatically manage signing: Checked
- Team: My Name (Personal Team)
- Provisioning Profile: None Required
- Signing Cert: Development

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into each one of the six targets and set your team. Worked for me.

[image]